# Ruby give class variable include

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance, module, include

I am playing with modules and classes to get something done.

When I fire up MyClass without any kind of inheritance I used `class MyClass::A4.generate`, where A4 overrides the format function.

A4 looks like this:

```
class A4 < MyClass
  def somefunction
    format = { :width => 200, :height => 100 }
  end
end
```

But now I would want to create multiple classes (generating different kind of files) onto a couple of formats.

My first attempt was a `class MyClass < AnotherClass` but this is more some kind of trying Javacode in Ruby, well that's what a lot of people on internet say.

Now the second attempt is a bit more Ruby like:

```
module AnotherModule
 def somefunction
   format = { :width => 50 }
 end
end

class MyClass
  include AnotherModule
  def initialize
  end
  ......
end
```

Is something like this possible?

```
class A4 < AnotherModule
  def somefunction
    format = { :width => 200, :height => 100 }
  end
end

MyClass::A4.new.generate
```

If so, how?

Comment: I don't get what do you want to end up having. Can you please rephrase?

Comment: to pass in a variable, will add a little bit

Comment: Well, still can't see what's your problem/question. You're saying something like "I have module A, and include it in class B. And there is C". Maybe some example of what you want to accomplish with C (i.e. A4) and how it relates to A/B (i.e. AnotherModule and MyClass) would be helpful.

Comment: 1. You can inherit from a module, 2. If `A4` is a separate class, not a class defined inside `MyClass`, why do you want to call it like `MyClass::A4.new.generate`?

Comment: And can you please provide some context on how `MyClass` and `AnotherModule` relates to `A4`?

Comment: Because MyClass fills the file, A4 gives the sizes, there are a few other than A4. I don't especially want `MyClass::A4.new.generate` just a way to use both.

Comment: AnotherModule has size, DPI settings etc, MyClass extends AnotherModule with the specifics for the template. A4 is one of the formats used in AnotherModule

Comment: Perhaps more simpler, is there a way to include from a variable?  (`var = A4(class with include AnotherModule)` => in MyClass: `include var`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't like your naming so from now on, let me call `Afile` what you called `MyClass` and `PrintSettings` what you called `AnotherModule`.

Presuming you have `PrintSettings`, `A4` and `Afile` defined like this

```
module PrintSettings
  # stuff
end

module A4
end

class Afile
  include PrintSettings
end
```

And now, you want to dynamically include `A4` (it's important `A4` is a module and not a class), you could do the following somewhere inside `Afile`

```
extend format

# example:

class Afile
  include PrintSettings

  def format=(new_format)
    extend new_format
  end
end

# and then using like:

file = Afile.new
file.format = A4
```

So, to sum up, when you want to mix-in a module at the time you define the class, you use `include`, and when you have an object, and want that object to extend some module, you use `extend`.

Comment: Then one Question, If I include `PrintSettings` in `A4` could I somehow include `A4` in `Afile` if a user chooses A4 as format?

Comment: As I showed in my answer, you can `extend var` to dynamically include the module (referenced to as `var` in this case).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly,

```
class A4 < AnotherModule
end

MyClass::A4.new.generate
```

The above code doesn run as expected, cos A4 class is extending a module which makes all the methods in `AnotherModule` as static methods in A4.

If generate is the method given by module AnotherModule,

```
`MyClass::A4.generate` will work.
```

http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/15/include-vs-extend-in-ruby/

Hope this helps.

Comment: The site was where I got the idea of the include line. It complains that MyClass is uninitialized

Comment: I did not understand what you meant exactly.

Comment: I had two classes, a generator and a generator_cut_lines. now these two are merged and the basic stuff is moved to a module, so I can create more kind of generators. But I think that with this move I've lost the possibility to set different formats (in the module). I.e. I have a few pictures of Van Gogh, which I want on A5 format, but I also have a some other pictures about him, which I want on A4 format. I think this would be possible through the same module, but how can I change the format inside the module. (this module is given to MyClass, which uses prawn to fill it in)